# Dimension of the Lie algebra of $SO(n,k)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $SO(n,k)$ denote the special generalized orthogonal group. Of course, $SO(n,k)$ is a Lie group. I know that the Lie algebra $so(n,k)$ of $SO(n,k)$ coincides with the Lie algebra of $O(n,k)$. I'd like to know the dimension of $so(n,k)$. I do not need a proof, I'm just curious about it.

Comment: The Lie algebra of a Lie group is isomorphic to the group's tangent space at the identity and therefore has the same dimension as the group.

Comment: @gofvonx: So, in this case the dimension would be 6, right?

Comment: I am by no means an expert, so take it with a grain of salt, but I think you are right here. Maybe, you will want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Relation_to_Lie_groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that that notation $so(n, k)$ means signature of a quadratic form (it also could be dimension and basic field, and quadratic form is a standard form ...)

Dimension of $so(Q)$ does not depend on the quadratic form $Q$, in fact, for any form there is explicit isomorphism of $so(Q)$ and space of skew-symmetric matrices (only as vector spaces!). Therefore, for any signature of a quadratic form dimension is the same $(n+k)(n+k-1)/2$.

I don't want to copy this construction here, but it is explained in the Fulton and Harris book "Representation theory. First course" in the section 20.1, in my edition it is formula 20.4.

Comment: I meant the dimension of $so(n,k)$ as a vector space. Anyway, thanks for the reference.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote, dimension of so(n,k) as a vector space is (n+k)(n+k−1)/2.